# Nested for loop in Python in single line - iterate with array

Tags: python, arrays, excel, loops

I have very long nested for loop, and I believe I can make it shorter using one-line notation. 
But here I am struggling with array iteration in nested single-line. I will appreciate your help and suggestions.
My function checks if I have empty cell in my Excel table and if not, go to the next cell in the row. If cell is not empty, I need to add every value to an array and create another array respectively to value in the column head. For every value in the cell I need to add the same amount of items with the value in the head. 
For example,

```
A              B      C       D
50             30     10      1
Danny, Sarah   Lenny  NaN     Mary
```

Will return two arrays:

```
prob_arr = [50, 50, 30, 1]
val_arr = ['Danny', 'Sarah', 'Lenny', 'Mary']
```

Here goes my function:

```
def concatvals(row, col, width, start, stop):
    prob_head = list(df)[start:stop]
    val_arr = []
    prob_arr = []
    j = 0
    for i in range(width):
        value_temp = df.iloc[row, col]
        if isinstance(value_temp, float) is False:
            value = [x.strip() for x in value_temp.split(',')]
            k = 0
            for k in range(len(value)):
                prob_arr.append(prob_head[i])
                k+=1
            for i in range(len(value)):
                val_arr.append(value[i])
        else:
            num_empty = j+1
            for k in range(num_empty-1):
                prob_arr.append(prob_head[i])
                k+=1
                for i in range(num_empty):
                    val_arr.append[value[i]]
            pass
        col+=1
        randparameter = random.choices(val_arr, prob_arr, k = 1)
    print(val_arr,prob_arr, randparameter)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you've nested a `for i in range` loop within another? Why do you think list comprehension will solve your problems?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it just doesn't check every value and doesn't seem to work properly, missing empty row and avoids another iteration.

Comment: If you have any suggestions to create a function needed in a different way, I would accept all your ideas and will try to apply it to my code.

Comment: My point is that you've overwrote the other i value. Also, the skipping might be related to the fact that you have `k+=1` in a loop that already increments the value.. That's how for loops over ranges work

Comment: I am totally stuck. For now it works, but I want to simplify. I have no idea where to move.

Comment: @AliceJarmusch please provide the code for the creation of the df, so it could be tested

Comment: If this code works, then perhaps you should post for a review. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: As an aside, `if isinstance(value_temp, float) is False:` is unecessary. Just use `if isinstance(value_temp, float)`

Comment: Also, why are you setting `k=0` outside a for-loop, then incrementing `k += 1` inside the loop body? These are totally useless. `k` gets assigned the value of the next item returned by the iterator every iteration, so the effects of `k += 1` are never seen, and for that matter, neither is `k = 0`

Comment: More to the point of your question: list comprehensions are not simply "one-line" notation meant to be equivalent to for-loops. They are functional programming constructs with very specific use-cases. From what I can tell, you don't want a list comprehension, you want a for-loop.